# How to force all new windows to open in primary monitor on GNOME?

Tags: linux, gnome, display, multi-monitor, display-settings

I am currently using two monitors side-by-side with my Linux desktop running GNOME. I have been using the `Join Displays` option to make the most out of my space. As time progressed new windows started appearing on weird places. Some on the primary display, some on the secondary display. In some cases half of the window is out of the display or completely shrinked with only the title bar visible.

To fix this behavior, if a program opens on the second display, I tried dragging it to the primary display then exiting in it. However the system does not seem to honor it and still opens the program on display #2 next time. For instance, when clicking `.pdf` files in `Nautilus`, `Evince` started opening on the sub display. I manually moved it to the primary display, kept it open then closed it. But the next time it just opened on the sub anyway.

I have no idea how the system decides which display's which area will be used when spawning a new window. Is there a config that I can tweak so that all windows must open in primary?