# Mate: How to change the default monitor that Chrome (or any app) opens on?

Tags: chrome, window-manager, mate-desktop, mx-linux

I am currently on MX Linux 21.3 and the desktop is Mate.

I have two monitors: an LCD TV and the laptop's built-in monitor. `xrandr` output is attached at the end. The LCD TV is at 1360x768 (primary) and the built-in monitor is at 1366x768 (right, with some Y-axis shift).

I notice that once I open Chrome, it always opens on the built-in monitor. My guess is that the center of the virtual screen is on the built-in monitor because it is slightly wider. However, my Firefox does not have this problem. It seems to remember where it was and opens on my LCD TV automatically.

My goal is to make my Chrome open on the LCD TV by default. I wonder if Chrome itself has any setting that allows this. Also, is it possible to change the behavior for any app, so that instead of attempting to open at the center of the virtual screen, open at the top-left corner instead?

##### `xrandr` output

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 2726 x 1144, maximum 16384 x 16384
VGA-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
LVDS-0 connected 1366x768+1360+376 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 309mm x 174mm
   1366x768      60.00*+
HDMI-0 connected primary 1360x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1920x1080     60.00 +  59.94    30.00    29.97    24.00    23.98    60.00  
   1360x768      60.02* 
   1280x768      59.99  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       59.94    59.93
```

---

I found [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/751809/how-to-force-all-new-windows-to-open-in-primary-monitor-on-gnome) but it does not have an answer yet, and it is about GNOME.

Comment: Chrome remembers the window position it was open before you close it. Open Chrome, move the window to the screen you want, close Chrome, open Chrome again.

Comment: @Marco Not the case for me. I move it to my LCD TV and close it. When I reopen, upper half of the window is in no-monitor area above the built-in monitor, and the lower half is on the built-in monitor.

Comment: have you tried to force the position (and size) via command-line option: `google-chrome --window-position=0,0 --window-size=1360,768`

Comment: [devilspie2](https://www.nongnu.org/devilspie2/)

Comment: @Marco It does not work either. `google-chrome --window-position=0,450` can put the new window nicely on the right monitor (built-in LCD). Changing y number can move it up and down. However, setting x number to a negative int does not move the new window further to the left to the left monitor.

Comment: I don't expect negative numbers to work. Anyway, this was my last idea. Maybe somebody else can help further.

Comment: @Marco I see what you are trying to do but I feel like it might be a bug. (0, 0) should be at top left.

Comment: @Marco The problem mysteriously went away today. -> I mean if I open it, now it opens maximized on left monitor directly. Have not validated the (0, 0) problem yet. Last night I installed some updates but Chrome was not among them... Weird.

Comment: @Marco Well... no. After a reboot it is back to what it was before.